# When using `nowrap` within a flex row, avoid pushing the last elements off the screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nowrap

I need to render a long text within a one line. and an image in the end of the line (tight end of the screen).

Given a very long text, I have to simply truncate it.
The text should now go into a second line because it is too long.

please see my code.
how can avoid pushing the nice emoji out of the screen?

Please take into account that the elements on the right side might be dynamic. so giving a fixed width is not good enough.

```css
div {
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Give the emoji span a width? 45px does it for that red dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `<span>` elements are `overflow:hidden`, the second `<span>` gets truncated as well.

One solution is to set only the text element to truncate.
Below, I've demonstrated that this also works with multiple icons.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="text">hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

---

Another solution is to prevent the icon from shrinking by setting [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) to zero.
Below, I'm using the [`flex` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to set `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`.
(Also works with icons of varying widths and with multiple icons.)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, just mentioed in my question - the emoji to the right is not fixed width. it can any width (in real-life scenario, there can 2 or 3 emojis to the right). i need a dynamic solution and not fixed pixels solution.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

You basically just need to remember that flex items can shrink by default (`flex-shrink: 1`).

Once you disable `flex-shrink` you should be all set.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;    /* optional */
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  /* optional */
}

span:last-child {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```