# having flex-parent disrupts a single-item flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox

further scaling up this recent question:

> [When using `nowrap` within a flex row, avoid pushing the last elements off the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49056401/when-using-nowrap-within-a-flex-row-avoid-pushing-the-last-elements-off-the-s)

I am struggling to understand why having a single flex parent - disrupts the otherwise perfect layout suggested in the referenced question.

**the expected behavior:**  the text will be cut, giving space to the emojis on the far side. no horizontal scrolling.

Please try to toggle `flex` property on and off to understand the behavior.

Also, Please note that understanding why the wrapping flex disrupts the layout, is my main goal in this question. so working around it will not be enough.

Is there a way to fix this behavior without strange solution like `flex-direction: column` ?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.single-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex">
  <div class="single-flex">
    <span>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`flex-shirnk` also didnt have any effect here.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i edited the question so it will be more clear. see `expected behavior` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `style="display:flex"` from the first div.

Then add a `margin-left: auto` to the first `.icon` so the red circles are on the right side when there isn't much text.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.single-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.icon {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.push {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="single-flex">
    <span>hello hello </span>
    <span class="icon push"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="single-flex">
    <span>hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello </span>
    <span class="icon push"></span>
    <span class="icon"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. My focus is understanding why the extra flex is causing this horizonal scorlling. I will further clarify it in my question.

Comment: But why would you do that, it doesn't have any function like that.

Comment: my real-life parent div has more things to it. i'm just trying to post here the most possible minimal markup for the sake of simlicity.

Comment: Okay, but apparently it is of more influence to the question than you think... so I would suggest to add it...